# Get records that have exactly (n) records in a row continuously

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Please consider this records:

| Name | Year | Season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | 2011 | 1 |
| Name1 | 2011 | 2 |
| Name2 | 2012 | 1 |
| Name2 | 2012 | 2 |
| Name2 | 2012 | 3 |
| Name2 | 2012 | 4 |
| Name3 | 2012 | 3 |
| Name3 | 2012 | 4 |
| Name4 | 2012 | 1 |
| Name4 | 2012 | 4 |
| Name5 | 2012 | 3 |
| Name5 | 2012 | 4 |
| Name5 | 2013 | 1 |
| Name5 | 2013 | 2 |

I want to get records that have 4 record in 4 seasons in a row. For example for above records I want to get `Name2` and `Name5` because `Name2` has 4 records in each season in 2012 and `Name5` has 4 records for 4 seasons in a row (for years 2012 and 2013). I tried to partition these records with `Row_Number` but it failed when we have 4 records in different years.

How can I achieve my desire result?

If I have below records for `Name3`:

| Name | Year | Season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  |  |
| Name3 | 2014 | 1 |
| Name3 | 2014 | 2 |
| ... |  |  |

then `Name3` wouldn't add to result because it hasn't 4 records for 4 seasons continuously.

Comment: What is your exact definition of `4 record in 4 seasons in a row`? Can you have a gap in `Year` or `Season`? You need to show more sample data and the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel: I want to get records that have 4 records for 4 season continuously. I can't have a gap.

Comment: Don't store your dates as separate year/season columns.  Use proper dates.

Comment: @Tim: Unfortunately, this is not possible. I get the records from an external resource.

Comment: Missing your attempt.

Comment: @DaleK: Yes I know but I tried to use `Row_Number` and `Rank` but I couldn't write a query because of `Year`. I mean I think I should write conditional `Partition` part but I can't.

Comment: You'll need a Seasons lookup table then which will allow you to assign IDs to the seasons chronologically and know that if Y2011S4 is n then Y2012S1 is n+1. That in conjunction with the `LAG()` or `LEAD()` functions will allow you to find islands with four consecutive seasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no duplicates:

- You can assign a code to each row by multiplying the `Year` by `4` then adding the `Season`.
- Then get the row 3 previous to this using `LAG`.
- Then aggregate, and ensure using a `HAVING` clause that there is at least one row where the row 3 previous to it is exactly 3 seasons earlier.

```sql
SELECT
  Name
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      SeasonCode = Year * 4 + Season,
      Prev4SeasonCode = LAG(Year * 4 + Season, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year, Season)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
GROUP BY
  Name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Prev4SeasonCode = SeasonCode - 3 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Tdg7kL4)

Instead of using a `SeasonCode`, you could also do multiple conditions on `Year` and `Season`.

Comment: Excellent. Short and useful.

Comment: I think I understood your query generally but could you explain `Having` please. Thanks

Comment: It's a conditional aggregation: count the number of rows for which the `CASE` returns a non-null value, then make sure that count > 0. The `CASE` checks if the current row's code - 3 is the same as the row 4 previous.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by using a technique called gaps and island:

```sql
SELECT  Name, groupFlag
,   MIN(Year) AS StartYear
,   MIN(Year * 10 + Season) % 10 AS StartSeason
,   MAX(Year) AS EndYear
,   MAX(Year * 10 + Season) % 10 AS EndSeason
FROM    (
    select  SUM(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Year, Season ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS groupFlag
    ,   *
    from (
        select  case when Season = prevseason % 4 + 1 and year =  prevYear + case when prevseason = 4 then 1 else 0 end then 0 else 1 end as flag
        ,   *
        FROM    (
            select  *
            ,   lag(year) over(partition by name order by year, season) as prevYear
            ,   lag(Season) over(partition by name order by year, season) as prevSeason
            from (
                VALUES  (N'Name1', 2011, 1)
                ,   (N'Name1', 2011, 2)
                ,   (N'Name2', 2012, 1)
                ,   (N'Name2', 2012, 2)
                ,   (N'Name2', 2012, 3)
                ,   (N'Name2', 2012, 4)
                ,   (N'Name3', 2012, 3)
                ,   (N'Name3', 2012, 4)
                ,   (N'Name4', 2012, 1)
                ,   (N'Name4', 2012, 4)
                ,   (N'Name5', 2012, 3)
                ,   (N'Name5', 2012, 4)
                ,   (N'Name5', 2013, 1)
                ,   (N'Name5', 2013, 2)
            ) t (Name,Year,Season)
            ) prev
        ) flag
    ) grp
GROUP BY Name, groupFlag
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
```

The way i do it is to get previous row data with help of LAG, then compare if previous YearSeason + 1 matches the current YearSeason, and set a flag being 0 and 1. For matches i use 0, for mismatches i set 1.

Then by doing an aggregated SUM OVER Partition, one calculates sum of those flags. This creates islands of matching group rows.

Finally, you can do the actual logic by counting each Name and GroupFlag-group and make sure it's >= 4.

Output:

| Name | groupFlag | StartYear | StartSeason | EndYear | EndSeason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name2 | 1 | 2012 | 1 | 2012 | 4 |
| Name5 | 1 | 2012 | 3 | 2013 | 2 |

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated it. You can just check each row if there is a row exactly 3 previous to it that is exactly 3 seasons earlier.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. I was focused on islands in case he wanted to see start and end. Really like your YEAR * 4 solution!

Comment: That wasn't the essential part of it, you can still use multiple conditions. You just don't need the `SUM` to check all previous rows.